# how to mock window.eventBus.$on - Vue.js | Jest Framework

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, jestjs, babel-jest

Need to test the emitted value for test case coverage.

```
window.eventBus.$on('filter-search-content', () => {
  console.log('Yes it was emitted');
  this.showFilter = true;
});
```

This what i have tried. But it's not worked out for me.

```
 it('should all the elements rendered', () => {
    global.eventBus = {
       $on: jest.fn(),
    }
    // global.eventBus.$emit('filter-search-content'); --> This also not working
    wrapper = mountAppointment(data);
    wrapper.vm.eventBus.$emit('filter-search-content');
    expect(wrapper.vm.showFilter).toBe(true);
 });
```

Comment: It's stubbed. Currently you can only check if $on was called as expected. You could expose a real event bus as a mock, otherwise you'll need to reimplement it

Answer (score -1):

Here is the example code we can follow.

```
emitEvent() {
  this.$emit("myEvent", "name", "password")
}
```

Here is the test case

```
describe("Emitter", () => {
 it("emits an event with two arguments", () => {
  const wrapper = shallowMount(Emitter)
   wrapper.vm.emitEvent()
   console.log(wrapper.emitted())
 })
})
```

Comment: Please check my code. Eventbus was used globally in my code. How i have to emit globally and listen on globally